# Validacion de Check con jquery no me funciona

Tags: html, jquery

tengo una pagina donde tengo N checkbox, de los cuales al menos uno debe estas tickeado antes de realizar el submit, tengo lo siguiente pero no me valida los check, alguien sabe por que?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código JS es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Debe seleccionar al menos un valor');
        }
    });
</script>
```

En la imagen se puede ver que el la UI tengo los check, tengo los archivos de jquery cargados y también se muestra la porción de código que debería validar los checks.

Comment: Deberías insertar los src javascript dentro del `<head></head>`

Comment: Por favor, no incluyas imagenes de código, directamente agrega el código en tu pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: Se que no te da una solución concreta, pero los grupos de radio buttons tienen ese comportamiento por defecto

Comment: mmmmm son checkbox no radios, ademas vi en muchas ejemplos que si funciona :

https://jsfiddle.net/miguelerm/GLd4f/

Pero a mi no.

Comment: @MikeVelazco en los grupos de radiobuttons solo puedes tener uno seleccionado, el OP quiere al menos uno pero pueden ser más, no creo que le sirva

Comment: Deberías reproducir el problema en tu pregunta. Pon código y no una imagen como te ha sugerido @MarcosGallardo. El código jquery está bien como has demostrado con el ejemplo de los comentarios así que el problema debe estar en otra parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas agregar todo dentro de un `$(document).ready()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){

    if (!$("input:checkbox:checked").length){
      alert("No hay checkbox 'checked'");
    }
            e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/belejutape/edit?html,output)

Comment: Así ya funciona, jejejeje pero ahora se me presento otro dilema, los checkbox se crean dinámicamente, o sea puede tener 0, 1 o N Checkbox, y pues cuando existe 0 (CERO) checkbox no me deja hacer submit, entonces como puedo hacer la validación únicamente cuando si existan checkbox?

Comment: Intenta cambiando el `$("input:checkbox").prop('checked').length` por `$("form").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked').length`

Comment: Para obtener el numero de existentes podrias utilizar `$("form").find("input:checkbox").length` y asi podrias utilizar `$("form").find("input:checkbox").length && !$("form").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked').length` dentro de tu `if`

Comment: No entiendo, con ese código siempre salta el alert, no importa si los checkbox están chequeados o no

Comment: @blonfu tiene razón. Solo hay que cambiar el selector. a `$('input:checkbox:checked')`

Comment: Huy ya se me presento otro dilema, tengo dos botones que hacen el submit en el mismo form (buscar y guardar), entonces necesito que la validación solo se la haga al submit del botón guardar y no del botón buscar, como hago para validar en el código que el botón que genero el submit sea el de guardar???

Comment: @RSillerico, Esta pagina existe para ayudar, no para hacerle la tarea/trabajo a alguien mas. Si deseas ayuda, al menos debes intentarlo tu mismo y haber buscado en otros medios (Google, Libros, etc.). Es por esto que se te pide poner el codigo en concreto y configuraciones en caso de ser necesarias.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
         if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length != 0){
            //OK
         }else{
           alert('Debe seleccionar al menos un valor');
           return false;
         }
    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final quedo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            if ($("form").find("input:checkbox").length > 0) {
                if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('Debe seleccionar al menos un valor');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

y funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Está sería la versión optimizada :D

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.on('submit', (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Si se va a enviar un AJAX
         if($form.find("input:checked").length > 0){
            //OK
         }
    });
   });
</script>
```

¿Por qué? por que al guardar el $formulario en una variable, ya no va a buscar otra vez en todo el DOM. asi como find, solo busca dentro del DOM elegido, en ves de todo el documento.

Y jquery recomienda no utilizar `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')`

https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Donde menciona eso-? Gracias